# problem getting value from HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Hi all I'm using a HashMap to hold one of my object with a string key. when I put an object with a key it has no problem, when I put my second object I got my object added but can't get it with its key. Somewhat it goes to somewhere that is "next". I took a screenshot from debug mode (eclipse), below

[image]

although size shows 2, I can't see my second item in hashmap, but in other hashmap's next node.

To note something I use my key like in a form "name.tag", tag and name in same time can never be the same, but "tag" can be the same. does hashmap has something to do with dot operator when evaluating keys? I hope I could write clearly,

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Here is a piece of code I use to create my hashmap

```
        private HashMap<String,ParameterItem> parseParametersNode(DataModel parent,Element element){
        NodeList parameterChilds=element.getChildNodes();//gep element parameters
        HashMap<String, ParameterItem> parameterItems=new HashMap<String, ParameterItem>();
        for(int i=0;i<parameterChilds.getLength();i++){
            if(parameterChilds.item(i).getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element el=(Element) parameterChilds.item(i);
                NamedNodeMap atts=el.getAttributes();
                ParameterItem item=new ParameterItem();

                for(int j=0;j<atts.getLength();j++){
                    Attr attribute=(Attr) atts.item(j);
                    String attributeValue=attribute.getValue();
                    String attributeName=attribute.getName();
                    item.setParsedProperty(attributeName, attributeValue);
            } /*check  attributes later*/
                //finish loop and insert paramitem to params
                String key="key"+i;
                if(item.getTag()!=null && item.getName()!=null)
                    key=item.getName()+"."+item.getTag();
                parameterItems.put(key, item);
//              testParam=item;
//              parameterItems.put(key, testParam);
                }
        }
        return parameterItems;

    }
```

Comment: show us the code where you add an remove things from the map

Comment: Can you post some code, specifically how you are adding items to the map and how you are getting the items.

Comment: may be both of the key are `equals`

Comment: i don't think there is anything to do with "." being used in the key. share your code for more..

Comment: I've added some codes @jigar : no dude the keys are not equals but one of keys like "a.123" and the other is "b.123" I don t think there is a problem with this

Comment: what about the code where you access/get them from the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really a problem here: you have a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29). That is, both of your keys have been placed in the same hash bucket. It appears you have only four buckets (odd, I thought the initial default was 10 or 16), so the chance of that with random data is 25 percent. Your size incremented just fine. The `next` is the internal implementation’s way of pointing to *the next element in the same bucket*. If the number of elements in each buckets gets too big, Java will internally *rehash* into more buckets.

I do not see why you need a HashTable here since you are numbering your keys consecutively (you could use an `ArrayList`), but maybe this is just starter code and your real use case is different.

Comment: Java's hash function uses chaining for resolving conflicts? I didn't know that, and wondered what the next was for when first looking at this. Should have made that connection.

Comment: Thanks Andrew but do you think it is normal to get no value of the key I added earlier and can you give a link that discusses this hash buckets and hashmap internals? And I use incremental keys for test purpose or in case oth er key is not th err e

Comment: No, if you put it in, you should be able to get it out. But I strongly suspect that you are accidentally using a different key, or that you stored null as the value associated with that key. You might look at the Javadoc for Hashtable http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html or Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 2):

You have the code:

```
String key="key"+i;
```

but right after this you set key again not adding to it:

```
if(item.getTag()!=null && item.getName()!=null)
              key=item.getName()+"."+item.getTag();
```

Should this be key +=item.getName()+"."+item.getTag(); ?